# Перехват трафика на Android

Tags: android, ssl, genymotion, reverse-engineering, fiddler

Мне необходимо перехватить запросы из мобильного приложения, чтобы воспользоваться его внутренним api. В приложении есть чат, мне необходимо получать ту информацию, которую сервер периодически присылает приложению.
Для этого я установил Genymotion с Xposed + модуль для обхода SSLPinning и Fiddler в качестве proxy (пробовал еще и Charles). После этого я вижу некоторую часть трафика из приложения (long-polling запросы), но вот нужные мне события не отображаются, хотя приложение по-прежнему их получает и отображает.

Можно ли как-то перехватывать абсолютно весь трафик из приложения и что для этого нужно сделать? Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Роскомнадзор решил глобально заняться проблемой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, дело в том, что настройки прокси в свойствах Wi-Fi подключения не являются системными и зачастую игнорируются приложениями. Чтобы решить эту проблему необходимо воспользоваться, например, приложением Postern, которое создаст виртуальное VPN подключение и перенаправит весь трафик с телефона по указанному вами адресу